# List results of exponentiation, with natural bases and exponents

Tags: induction, exponentiation

I am looking for a way to construct an ordered set like

$\{2^3, 2^4, 3^3, 2^5, 2^6, 3^4, 5^3, 2^7...\} = \{8, 16, 27, 32, 64, 81, 125, 128...\}$

Preferably, but not necessarily, with all bases $>1$, all exponents $>2$, and no duplicates (like $4^3 = 2^6$).

A helpful construction would be something like the following so I can proof stuff for the entire set, by induction:

First element = $2^3$. Given element $n$, the element $n+1$ is... or has the properties ...

Is there a known way to do it? Is there a known reason why it would be impossible?

*(... hope I have not mistranslated any words from german ...)*

Comment: I could not actually understand your question, the conditions you set without any restriction, calls for an infinite set, which is impossible to create.

Comment: Yes I am talking about an infinite set. Is construction the wrong word? I basically want a rule that tells me what the next element is, given an element.

Comment: To clarify: If the set would have the restriction on the bases to be 7, and the given element would be 7^n, then the next would be 7^(n+1)

Comment: Now I understand, you want a recurrence. That is possible, but you need to extend your requirement more, because more than one recurrence is possible for the same elements.

Comment: The problem of devising an algorithm to enumerate these values efficiently and in ascending order is called [Hamming's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_problem#Algorithms), but I'm not aware of any closed form, which would imply a constant-time algorithm.

Comment: Why did you omit $5^2$?

Comment: @Hawk: Thanks. So I am actually talking about a sequence here :)

Comment: @MJD: Interesting pointer, thanks. I omitted the $5^2$, because I would love to have just the elements with exponents >2, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

A common strategy for this sorry of problem is to start with the numbers $a^b$ where $a+b=5$, ordered, say, in increasing order of $a$, then move on to totals of 6, etc. So your sequence would start $ 2^3,3^2,2^4,3^3,4^2,2^5,...$.

The rule for getting to the next number is then "increase the base and decrease the exponent by 1 unless the exponent is 2 in which case...".

This, of course, counts duplicates, and the rule relies on you knowing the base and the exponent not just the resulting number. I would think a rule that meets these criteria would be pretty difficult to come up with.

Comment: Thanks. This actually gets me one step closer. Having the base and exponent for a given element, is also not a problem for the stuff I am working on. The thing I really need badly, is the property of the next element having a greater value than the given element.